# CRT terminators(VC)

Tags: c++, crt

I registered a terminator function on ".CRT$XTU" section, but the function is not be called when application exits.

**CODE BLOCK 1:**

```
typedef int (__cdecl *_PVFV)();
static int __cdecl on_process_term()
{
    //do something
    return 0;
}
#pragma section(".CRT$XTU",long,read)
__declspec(allocate(".CRT$XTU"))_PVFV my_process_terminator= on_process_term;
```

I registered *on_process_term()* , but my test application never reaches *on_process_term()* function.

I traced the crt source code, found that it seems like this is because my exe application is  dynamic linked with crt dll.

**CODE BLOCK 2:**

```
#ifndef CRTDLL
        /*
         * do terminators
         */
        _initterm(__xt_a, __xt_z);
#endif  /* CRTDLL */
```

The code in "code block 2" can be found in *doexit()* function which is called by *exit()* function.

Macro CRTDLL is defined because my exe is dynamic linked with crt dll(msvcr110.dll?), so 
*_initterm(__xt_a, __xt_z);* this line is "commented out". So any terminators would not be called.

**CODE BLOCK 3:**

```
/***
* __crtdll_callstaticterminators
*
*Purpose:
*       call terminators. This is called from CRT_INIT when dll entrypoint is
*       called with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH. We can't call the terminators from exit
*       as there may be some dll that may need crt functionality during
*       DLL_PROCESS_DETACH
*
*******************************************************************************/
void __crtdll_callstaticterminators(void) {
    /*
     * do pre-terminators
     */
    _initterm(__xp_a, __xp_z);

    /*
     * do terminators
     */
    _initterm(__xt_a, __xt_z);
}
```

*__crtdll_callstaticterminators()* will be called when crt dll is detached from application, and do terminators. As document declares, crt dll is dynamic linked to my application, so code in "code block 2" is "commented out", and terminator functions will be called here. But, my *on_process_term* cann't be found in terminators from __xt_a to __xt_z in "code block 3". It seems like that terminators in "code block 2" are not as same as in "code block 3".

Any one would help me out of this problem?
  Why does *on_process_term* not be called? And how to make it be called?

Many thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity: How did you manage to dig that deep without using std::atexit ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to call it is to use the standard mechanism. In particular, `std::atexit`. That works the same regardless of how you link the CRT.